# How to transfer all stored procedures from one database to another with SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I just want to transfer all stored procedures from one database to another. SQL Server Management Studio only supports tables and views. Management Studio gives option to Import/Export data but only supports tables and views.

please help me.

Comment: ok. thanks it's easy to go with Generate Scripts and select Stored Procedure option and after that all stored procedure create to queries are generated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to extend answer from @Anup Agarwal,
 
Right Click on the database name 
--> click **Generate Scripts..** 
--> click <kbd>Next</kbd> 
--> choose **Select specific data objects** 
--> check **Stored Procedures** 
--> click <kbd>Next</kbd> 
--> choose **Save to new query window** 
--> click <kbd>Next</kbd> 
--> click <kbd>Finish</kbd>

Now, change the database name to the new database name in the query window and execute.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the database and point to **tasks** and click on **generate scripts**. Run these scripts on new database.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078(v=sql.105).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178078%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)